# How to change font size in yellowbrick classification report?

Tags: python, yellowbrick

See classification report produced by the code below. The text for the class labels, scores, and color bar are way too big. How can I make the text smaller?

```
for name, model in final_models:
    classes = ["unfavorable mRS (3-6)", "favorable mRS (0-2)"]
    class_vis = ClassificationReport(model, classes = classes, support = "percent")
    class_vis.score(X_test_trans, y_test)
    class_vis.show()
```

[image: Example of classification report]

Answer (score 0):

The lines of code below worked for me.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
```

Comment: Hi @MAR, Usually a code block with just a "try this" is not a very good answer. It helps the community much more if you could tell us why we should try this code and why it would/might help the op. Thanks!